# Efficent way to sort 'Person.firstName' under first alphabetically letter

Tags: ios, sorting, nsdictionary

I iterate through a long list of names, which I assign each to a 'Person' object. A `Person` object has a `firstName` and a `lastName`. I am looking for a efficent way to sort all the `firstNames` beginning with the letter `A` through `Z`. I have come up with this solutions but it is not efficent, or there is surely an easier way than creating '24' arrays for each letter of the alphabet.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

    ...

    if ([person.firstName hasPrefix:@"A"] || [person.firstName hasPrefix:@"a"]) {
            [self.letterA_Array addObject:person];//NSMutableArray

        }

    ...
  }
```

I would like something similar like the below example if it will work with objects, but I am unsure:

```
NSDictionary *animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
            @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
            @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
            @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
            @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
            @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],
            @"K" : @[@"Koala"],
            @"L" : @[@"Lion", @"Llama"],
            @"M" : @[@"Manatus", @"Meerkat"],
            @"P" : @[@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear"],
            @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
            @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
            @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
            @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};
```

Comment: I think you mean efficient not sufficient ;-)

Comment: @MartinH haha you are right, its been a long day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Bob", @"Book2", @"August", @"Zulu", @"Agnoz"];
NSMutableDictionary *buckets = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *name in names) {
    NSString *index = [name substringToIndex:1];
    if (!buckets[index]) {
        buckets[index] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [buckets[index] addObject:name];
}
```